# Can a grid connected PV system deliver power backwards through the distribution transformer?

Tags: electrical-engineering, electrical, solar-energy, power-transmission, photovoltaics

If there is no local load demand can a residential roof top grid connected PV system deliver power across distribution transformer [up to the higher voltage grid]?

Suppose my grid connected solar pv system is in a residential area where load requirement is very low during day time. Will the power generated by my solar pv system deliver power across distribution transformer back to primary distribution where there can be industrial load.

I am asking because whether my rooftop grid connected PV system is profitable when local load is limited.

Comment: If there is no load then where would the power be delivered to?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! Just to clarify: are you asking if a rooftop solar panel can feed power into the grid?

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Let me clarify. Suppose my grid connected solar pv system is in a residential area where load requirement is very low during day time. Will the power generated by my solar pv system deliver power across distribution transformer back to primary distribution where there can be industrial load

Comment: Yes, he wants to know how far up the grid 4-quadrant machines go. Simple pole transformers will pass power both ways

Comment: Thank you for replying. Practically will power flow takes place between secondary to primary o distribution transformer. We consider grid has constant voltage right.

Comment: I know these things are basics but i am confused

Comment: @Nandu Please edit the question itself to clarify it, don't leave important information in the comments.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson thank you.

Comment: There is no difference between "primary" and "secondary" windings on a transformer. Those are just names that tell us how somebody _expected_ the transformer to be used, but they're both just coils of wire around the magnetic core. A transformer is like a mechanical gearbox. It can transmit power in either direction.